# Unable to upload my pods Use CocoaPods V1.0.0.beta.2

Tags: frameworks, cocoapods

My podspec file just like below

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s| 


s.name = "LTFramework1" 


s.version = "0.0.1" 


s.summary = "CocoaPods 测试." 


s.homepage = "https://github.com/limaofuyuanzhang/LTFramework1" 


s.license = "MIT" 


s.author = { "limaofuyuanzhang" => "397524331@qq.com" } 


s.social_media_url ="http://limaofuyuanzhang.gitcafe.io" 


s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'


s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/limaofuyuanzhang/LTFramework1.git", :tag => "0.0.1" } 

s.vendored_framework = "**/LTFramework1.framework"

s.requires_arc = true  
end
```

I can user it upload my framework account to CocoaPods 0.39.0，but when I update my CocoaPods to 1.0.0.beta.2, the podsepc doesn't work.The error below

```
/var/folders/d3/vxynt1496_34x3mt_576n4mm0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/App/main.m:3:9: fatal error: module 'LTFramework1' not found
@import LTFramework1;
 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/lintao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-extnutajzsresacludgticynatpq/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o App/main.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/lintao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-extnutajzsresacludgticynatpq/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o App/main.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
 -> LTFramework1 (0.0.1)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  /var/folders/d3/vxynt1496_34x3mt_576n4mm0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/App/main.m:3:9: fatal error: module 'LTFramework1' not found

Analyzed 1 pods
```

And I think is my podspec lack something,but Ican't find it on the official website.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has solve.I made a mistake.I just want to learn push my framework, so I just rename an old framework to `LTFramework1` instead of made a new one.And this framework can't use `@import LTFramework1` in project，but can user `@import <LTFramework1/xxx.h>`.I think when user `pod lib lint`, somewhere has use `@import <LTFramework1/xxx.h>` in CocoaPods 0.39.0 but use `@import LTFramework1` in CocoaPods 1.0.0.beta.2.

I'm still in the study of the difference between `@import module` and `@import <>`.I'm try to rename the header to `LTFramework1.h`,but it doesn't work.

Anyway, thank you very much for your view.My English is poor, please forgive me.